# How to clear or stop timeInterval in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am making a demo in which I am fetching data from the server after regular intervals of time using `$interval` Now I need to stop/cancel this.

How I can achieve this? If I need to restart the process, how should I do that?

Secondly, I have one more question: I am fetching data from the server after reqular intervals of time. Is there any need to use `$scope.apply` or `$scope.watch`?

Here is my plunker:

```
  app.controller('departureContrl',function($scope,test, $interval){
   setData();

   $interval(setData, 1000*30);

   function setData(){
      $scope.loading=true;
    test.stationDashBoard(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.data=data.data;
        $scope.loading=false;
        //alert(data);
    },function(error){
        alert('error')
    }) ;

   }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ly43m5?p=preview

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can store the promise returned by the interval and use `$interval.cancel()` to that promise, which cancels the interval of that promise. To delegate the starting and stopping of the interval, you can create `start()` and `stop()` functions whenever you want to stop and start them again from a specific event. I have created a snippet below showing the basics of starting and stopping an interval, by implementing it in view through the use of events (e.g. `ng-click`) and in the controller.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('ItemController', function($scope, $interval) {
  
    // store the interval promise in this variable
    var promise;
  
    // simulated items array
    $scope.items = [];
    
    // starts the interval
    $scope.start = function() {
      // stops any running interval to avoid two intervals running at the same time
      $scope.stop(); 
      
      // store the interval promise
      promise = $interval(setRandomizedCollection, 1000);
    };
  
    // stops the interval
    $scope.stop = function() {
      $interval.cancel(promise);
    };
  
    // starting the interval by default
    $scope.start();
 
    // stops the interval when the scope is destroyed,
    // this usually happens when a route is changed and 
    // the ItemsController $scope gets destroyed. The
    // destruction of the ItemsController scope does not
    // guarantee the stopping of any intervals, you must
    // be responsible for stopping it when the scope is
    // is destroyed.
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.stop();
    });
            
    function setRandomizedCollection() {
      // items to randomize 1 - 11
      var randomItems = parseInt(Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
        
      // empties the items array
      $scope.items.length = 0; 
      
      // loop through random N times
      while(randomItems--) {
        
        // push random number from 1 - 10000 to $scope.items
        $scope.items.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 10000 + 1)); 
      }
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ItemController">
  
  <!-- Event trigger to start the interval -->
  <button type="button" ng-click="start()">Start Interval</button>
  
  <!-- Event trigger to stop the interval -->
  <button type="button" ng-click="stop()">Stop Interval</button>
  
  <!-- display all the random items -->
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-bind="item"></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- end of display -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @thanks for reply ..is there any need to add apply or watch when i am fetching data from service reqular interval of time

Comment: No you don't need to use `apply()`, if you're using the `$interval` service, since it does that for you. But if you're using the built-in `setInterval()` then you might have to use `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: Very good solution. The `$destroy` works well together with the `http-auth-interceptor` like in my case where I want to stop the interval during auth failure (like expired session) and start again after succesfull auth. Thank you for this excellant solution.

Answer (score 41):

```
var interval = $interval(function() {
  console.log('say hello');
}, 1000);

$interval.cancel(interval);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var promise = $interval(function(){
    if($location.path() == '/landing'){
        $rootScope.$emit('testData',"test");
        $interval.cancel(promise);
    }
},2000);
```

Comment: Since URLs might change in the future I would think twice before using the `$location.path()` and not the state name

Answer (score 4):

When you want to create interval store promise to variable:

```
var p = $interval(function() { ... },1000);
```

And when you want to stop / clear the interval simply use:

```
$interval.cancel(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $scope.toggleRightDelayed = function(){
        var myInterval = $interval(function(){
            $scope.toggleRight();
        },1000,1)
        .then(function(){
            $interval.cancel(myInterval);
        });
    };
```