# How to stop a setInterval function from executing on an angular directive after route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am putting a gallery into a page via a directive.  The gallery desolves back and forth between images using javascript (I am planning to use css transitions to rotate through an array of classes).

I want a `setInterval` function to execute but only when the directive is on the page (which is to say only when a certain route is called). However, even when a new route is hit, and a new view is rendered on my page, the existing function is still executing.  For example:

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('gallery', function ($location) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      setInterval(function () {
        //This is where I would change the classes on the element
        //This will continually execute, even when on a different view
      }, 500);
    }
  });
```

**HTML view**

```
<div gallery>
    Something special
</div>
```

Is there any way for me to only execute the interval function when the directive is on the page?

Comment: Note that you should probably use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), but that wouldn't fix this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you. That hint led me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447923/how-to-clear-or-stop-timeinterval-in-angular-js which looks promising....(get it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cancel the interval on `$destroy` event.

```
var intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
  // do your operation
}, 500);

element.on('$destroy', function() {
   $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
});
```

Here is the link to documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: `$interval` returns a promise, not a timeoutId. Change the variable name and the answer would be cleaner.

Comment: @NewDev, I just took it from the official docs. Are you sure it is promise?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $interval:-

```
    var promise=$interval(function () {

    }, 500);
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 

        if(next!=current)
            $interval.cancel(promise);

    });
```

Or if you are using setInterval:-

```
var promise=setInterval(function () {
      }, 500);
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 

        if(next!=current)
           clearInterval(promise);

    });
```

Comment: This looks correct to me.  Why exactly is it a better idea to use `$interval` as opposed to the native javascript?

Comment: Because it is a angualr way to do it.It is working inside the $apply() cycle of angular.

Comment: This is not a good solution as it ties your directive to how the app changes views. Take a look at @UlanMurzatayev's answer that provides the more robust way

Comment: There is no need to watch for $locationChangeStart event, you can simply watch for $destroy event to be fired. It is fired whenever an element is removed from DOM.

Comment: ok so instead of listing the view we have to find inside the directive the view has been changed..??
With the help of $destroy.

Comment: `$destroy` is fired when the directive's scope is deleted, which happens when the directive is removed from the DOM with `ng-if`, for example, and, not coincidentally, also when you change Views.

Comment: But as far as i know he asked for the change in view not for the destroying of directive.If we refresh the page DOM will create agian and it also trends to destroy the directive but still view is same.
I dont know may be i m confused here a little sorry :-)

Comment: Yes, the OP asked for a change in View, but the more correct answer is not to tie the directive directly to the change view event. Directives are meant to be reusable. What if the app decides to use `$stateProvider` tomorrow? You would need to change your directive as well. And if directive is removed with `ng-if` the $interval is never cleared.