# $interval not working fine in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7354/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.timer = 0;
  $interval(
    function() {
      $scope.timer += 1000;
    }, 1000);
}
```

What's wrong with my code? $interval doesn't work although I pass the dependency correctly.

Comment: This is in the console output `Error: Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval` and secondly you were using Angular 1.0.1\

Comment: You have not specified `MyCtrl` as a `controller`

Comment: Please see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7355/)

Comment: @Karthik any idea how to clear interval?

Comment: @EuniceChia - Here you go!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447923

Comment: @Karthik http://jsfiddle.net/6yqnjewn/ tried :'(

Comment: Check this updated one..http://jsfiddle.net/6yqnjewn/2/. The reason is that, button is placed outside the scope of the controller and clear is not a function of `$interval`

Answer (score 0):

The error is `AngularJS Error: Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interva`

And the issue is

> The $interval service was added with version 1.2.0-rc.3 (See
>   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc3-ferocious-twitch-2013-10-14).
>   This error will happen with any version before this.

In the jsfiddle you angularjs version is `1.0.1`