# how to set interval only when there is a new data in database and stop when the data already arrived using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

hallo i want to make a live message for user to user using AngularJS, and i used interval to make the message comes from database  automatically/ without reload the page, but interval making reload every time and cannot stop.

and i want to make the interval stop when the data already arrives. below this message is my code

#### HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 wt-rounded-edge set-nego-chat-box" pesan id="show-pesan">
<!-- list of the message-->
</div>

// the input and button

 <textarea ng-model="databaru.pesan"></textarea>
<input type="text" ng-model="databaru.pesanwaktu">
 <button ng-click="tambahData()">Sent</button>
```

#### AngularJS

```
    var test = angular.module('tesApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment']);
test.factory('factoryPesan', function($http) {
    var factoryPesan = {};
    factoryPesan.getPesan = function() {
        return $http.get('get_data.php');
    };
    factoryPesan.putPesan = function($datas) {
        return $http.post('add_data.php', $datas);
    };
    return factoryPesan;
});
/*--------------get the data--------------*/
test.directive('pesan', function() {
    return {
        restirct: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'mymessage.php',
        controller: function($scope, factoryPesan, $interval, $timeout) {
            /*--------------------my interval start here----------------------------------*/
            $scope.getData = function() {
                factoryPesan.getPesan().success(function(hasil) {
                    $scope.data = hasil;
                });
            };
            $scope.intervalFunction = function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.getData();
                    $scope.intervalFunction();
                }, 3000)
            };
            $scope.intervalFunction();
        }
    };
});
/* -------------------------end of interval-----------------------*/
/*--------------controller to put the data in database--------------*/
test.controller('livechat', function($scope, $timeout, $http, factoryPesan, dataService) {
    $scope.tambahData = function() {
        databaru = {
            pesan: $scope.databaru.pesan,
            pesanwaktu: $scope.databaru.pesanwaktu
        };
        factoryPesan.putPesan(databaru).success(function(hasil) {
            $scope.data.push({
                pesan: $scope.databaru.pesan,
                pesanwaktu: $scope.databaru.pesanwaktu
            });
            $scope.databaru.pesan = '';
            $scope.status = 'oke';
        });
    };
});
```

how to fix this, so the point is how to make reload when there is any new data in database and stop when a new data is arrives.

Comment: Duplicate post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447923/how-to-clear-or-stop-timeinterval-in-angularjs

Comment: not duplicate, i want to make the interval running when there have a new data in database, and stop running when the data is arrives @Babydead. please help

Comment: Yes, so you once you get the data from the function, you clear the interval, as is shown how to do in the question I linked to. Am I misunderstanding this? -- I don't know angularJS specifically very well, but it's basic javascript structure. Set an interval on an ajax call -> data received -> clear interval

Comment: okay thanks i will try first hank you @Babydead