# Stop interval function when changing site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am writing a website using `react` . In one component I have a `setInterval()` function which gets executed, it updates them `DOM`. Now, when I change onto another site with my router (`react-router-dom`) the `setInterval()` function crashed, because it cannot find the `DOM` elements to update. How do I go on about this? I though I use `componentWillUnmount()` but the same error occurs.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            stop: false,
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if(!this.state.stop) {
            this.setState({
                stop: true,
            })
        }
    }

    _stop = (counter) => {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }

    _someFunc = () =>  {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        ...
        const update = setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById('some-id').innerText = this._someFunc();
        }, 1000);

        if(this.state.stop) {
            this._stop(update)
        }

        return (
                <p id='some-id'></p>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

How do I stop the interval?

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447923/how-to-clear-or-stop-timeinterval-in-angularjs

Comment: check if element exists before putting text to it.

Comment: @SenadMeškin that creates tons of unnecessary if/else questions.

Comment: seems like you should call stop in the unmount section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

**1-** Put the timer outside of the render method, better to use componentDidMount lifecycle method. By this way timer will be registered only once and after each 1ms it will execute the callback method.

**2-** Store the timer id in a variable (in instance) to stop it before leaving the page.

Like this:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            stop: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById('some-id').innerText = this._someFunc();
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._stop();
    }

    _stop = () => {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    _someFunc = () =>  {
        ...
    }

    render() {

        return (
                <p id='some-id'></p>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Ah, so its only the `this.timerId = setInterval ...` thats different to `const update = setInterval....`? Why do I need to store it in a class(?) variable and cannot store the interval the way I did it?

Comment: if you set the value in local variable, it will not be available in all the functions. if you store in class instance it will be available easily.

Comment: also issue with your code was, on each re-rendering of the component a new timer will be registered instead of using the same, to avoid that put a check before using setInterval :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a performance optimization then do it **react way**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39426527/6124657