# AngularJS $interval dont stop on .cancel();

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, setinterval

I have SPA multi view application in AngularJS, I have defined $interval which is started from another view Controller. When i click a btn with function called and line $interval.cancel(); in it, it does not stop.

Here are examples of my code:

MainController:

```
 $scope.$on("startInterval", function () {
    $interval(function warningsControl() {
        console.log("Timer stamp!");

        $.ajax({
            // some web api call which works fine
        })
    }, 10000);
});

$scope.stop = function () {
    $interval.cancel();
}

$scope.logoutButton = {
    text: "Logout",
    type: "normal",
    visible: false,
    onClick: function () {

        // some working code

        $scope.stop();

        var logoutBtn = $("#logout-btn").dxButton("instance");
        logoutBtn.option({
            visible: false
        });
    }
}
```

And SecondController:

```
$scope.authenticateButton = {
    type: "default",
    text: "Log In",
    onClick: function () {

        $.ajax({
            // some web api calling
            success: (data) => {
                // some working code
                $rootScope.$broadcast("startInterval");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This code start interval and everithing is running OK, until the point i click Logout btn - it made everithing except stoping the interval.

Any ideas how to fix it? I would be grateful for advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear or stop timeInterval in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447923/how-to-clear-or-stop-timeinterval-in-angularjs)

Comment: I looked at it before, there i find line $interval.cancel() is used for stoping interval, but it does not work in my code and I could not find any answer for my problem there.

Comment: Judging from the answer in the linked dupe, you need to store the interval and pass it to `cancel()`. "Doesn't work" is not helpful; are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: Console is without errors (except of those, where program calls server without logged user - $interval still running but it should not). But thanks to Quantum's answer i managed to made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $interval function should return some sort of ID which you can pass into $interval.cancel(). For example:

```
var int_id = $interval( func, time )
//...later...
$interval.cancel(int_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot to save $interval in variable and then send it to the cancel funcion. This was thanks to my misunderstanding of $interval at all.